# Firebase cloud functions folder not showing

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, react-native-firebase

I am using firebase with react native . Trying to write some firebase cloud functions. For that i have used `firebase init` . On console it gives a success message but the function folder is not been created in my project .
I have tried several times re initializing the firebase init but no result.

[image]

Comment: update NPM, make sure you are in the right directory?

Comment: @Yewla I have read the documentation. The first time when I initialized it showed up but after committing to Github and opening it the next day it wasn't there.

Comment: try a new folder location. At the top it says you are trying to create it in users/haseeb.  ( is this your intent? Create a new folder wherever youd like and 'CD' into it before you initialize.  i.e. users/haseeb/project  and see if it then creates it.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: Yup creating a new folder by the name of backend and initializing there worked for me. and then I have to move the functions folder to the root level of the project. Thankyou @Yewla

Comment: @Yewla, please post your last comment as an answer, since it solved this question.

Answer (score 2):

Try a new folder location. Create a new folder by the name of the backend wherever you'd like and 'CD' into it before you initialize it. i.e. `users/haseeb/project` and see if it then creates it.

Then, move the functions folder to the root level of the project.